# FindWindow() doesn't find my window [C++]

Tags: hwnd, findwindow

This is not a complex question. I'm having trouble finding the handle that belongs to iTunes. But although iTunes is running in the background, it keeps telling me it can't find the window. So I went on checking whether I miss typed the window name, but spy++ pointed out to me that I was using the correct window name and class name (see below). I'm sure it's a small mistake but I can't seem to find it. Does anyone have an insight? Thanks in advance.

```
        HWND hwnd;
        hwnd = FindWindow((LPCWSTR)"iTunes",(LPCWSTR)"iTunes");
    if (hwnd != 0){
        cout << "WINDOW FOUND" << endl;
    } else { 
        cout << "WINDOW NOT FOUND" << endl; 
        cout << hwnd << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using ANSI strings with what appears to be the Unicode version of `FindWindow`.

Many Win32 functions are actually a pair of function and a macro. For example, `FindWindow` is defined approximately like this:

```
HWND WINAPI FindWindowA(LPCSTR lpClassName, LPCSTR lpWindowName);
HWND WINAPI FindWindowW(LPCWSTR lpClassName, LPCWSTR lpWindowName);

#if (UNICODE)
#  define FindWindow FindWindowW
#else
#  define FindWindow FindWindowA
#endif
```

Try explicitely calling `FindWindowA` or using wide strings like this:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(L"iTunes", L"iTunes");
```

Comment: It's no problem at all. Keep in mind you should almost never need to cast when using Win32. If you are, you're probably passing the wrong parameters; that's how I figured out which version of FindWindow you were calling.